# laravel newsletter spatie is not installing in laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I am trying to install spatie laravel newsletter package but i am getting an error message

> Problem 1
> - Root composer.json requires spatie/laravel-newsletter ^4.9 -> satisfiable by spatie/laravel-newsletter[4.9.0].
> - spatie/laravel-newsletter 4.9.0 requires illuminate/support ^6.0|^7.0|^8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev,
> v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded,
> likely because it conflicts with another require.
>
> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to
> their original content.

my composer.json file looks like this

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "gufy/pdftohtml-php": "~2",
        "intervention/image": "^2.5",
        "jenssegers/agent": "^2.6",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

Not able to understand how to resolve the issue. I can't upgrate laravel 5.8 to 8 because it will take a lot of time.

Comment: Could you add the command you used to try and install the package with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Packagist page for [spatie/laravel-newsletter](https://packagist.org/packages/spatie/laravel-newsletter) and find a version of the package that supports Laravel 5.8.

Looks like 4.8.2 will do:

[image: Packagist page]

Run `composer require "spatie/laravel-newsletter:~4.8.2"`.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot! Learned something new from you! You are awesome